# pass dataframe output to udf pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script with some UDF's that makes changes to a dataframe using mainly list comprehensions:

```
def createclaimfields(field,master):
    print 'creating unique matter ids for {} at {}'.format(field,getdt())
    dfcol = ['MATTER ID',field]
    df = master[dfcol].dropna().drop_duplicates()
    print 'created unique matter ids for {} at {}'.format(field,getdt())

    print 'started getting CLASS HYBRID claims for {} at {}'.format(field,getdt())
    df['{} CLASS HYBRID CLM NO'.format(field)]=[getclasshybrid(clm) for clm in df[field]]
    print 'finished getting CLASS HYBRID claims for {} at {}. Found {} matches'.format(field,getdt(),len(df['{} CLASS HYBRID CLM NO'.format(field)]))

    print 'started getting HRV claims for {} at {}'.format(field,getdt())
    df['{} HRV CLM NO'.format(field)]=[gethrv(clm) for clm in df[field]]
    print 'finished getting HRV claims for {} at {}. Found {} matches'.format(field,getdt(),len(df['{} HRV CLM NO'.format(field)]))

    print 'started getting CC claims for {} at {}'.format(field,getdt())
    df['{} CC CLM NO'.format(field)]=[getcc(clm) for clm in df[field]]
    print 'finished getting CC claims for {} at {}. Found {} matches'.format(field,getdt(),len(df['{} CC CLM NO'.format(field)]))

    print 'started getting PASS claims for {} at {}'.format(field,getdt())
    df['{} PASS CLM NO'.format(field)]=[getpass(clm) for clm in df[field]]
    print 'finished getting PASS claims for {} at {}. Found {} matches'.format(field,getdt(),len(df['{} PASS CLM NO'.format(field)]))

    print 'merging {} into claimfields at {}'.format(field,getdt())
    master = master.merge(df,how='left',on=['MATTER ID',field])
    print 'merged {} into claimfields at {}'.format(field,getdt())

    return master

fieldlist = ['MATTER NUMBER','MATTER NAME','CLAIM NUMBER LISTING'] 
mattercol = ['MATTER NUMBER','MATTER NAME','CLAIM NUMBER LISTING','MATTER ID']
claimfields = rawtrans[mattercol].dropna().drop_duplicates().head()

[createclaimfields(field,claimfields) for field in fieldlist]
```

Unfortunately when I call `claimfields` after running this I get the original output without the added columns. I'm guessing this is because 'claimfields' is calling the function 'rawtrans[mattercol].dropna().drop_duplicates().head()' rather than the actual output of that function call. How do define claimfields as it's own object rather than as a chain of commands stemming from the 'rawtrans' df?

Thanks!

EDIT:: Problem solved! I replaced `[createclaimfields(field,claimfields) for field in fieldlist]` with the following:

```
for field in fieldlist:
    claimfields=createclaimfields(field,claimfields)
```

tl;dr I wasn't assigning the output dataframe correctly, and I also didn't need to use a list comp to iterate through each field in fieldlist.

EDIT #2 - sample UDF

```
def getcc(clm):
    zlist=range(len(clm))

    #create list of prefixes from letterlist and numberlist
    prefixlist = ['AA','AB','AC','AD','AE','AF','GA','GB','GC','GD','GE','GF','ZZ']

    # list of all 20 length substrings for list comprehension below
    clmstrs=[x for x in [clm[z:z+8] for z in zlist] if (len(x)==8) & (any(p in x[:-2] for p in prefixlist)) & sum(c.isalpha() for c in x)==2]

    if (len(clmstrs)> 0):
        return clmstrs[0]
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Comment: Please set up a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example: 1) input data sample, 2) runnable code, 3) desired result. We cannot see the other methods `getclasshybrid()`, `gethrv()`,  `getpass()`. This almost feels like you want to pivot your data. Pandas has many such methods.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to keep it from getting too big. I did figure out the issue; I wasn't assigning the output correctly.

Comment: I still feel these many list comprehensions are not necessary. Would be helpful to see some data. Good luck with project though.

Comment: you were right! too many list comps. in case you're curious, the goal of the script is to iterate through user inputted strings and pull out numbers that match certain formatting. each udf starting with 'get' (getpass(), getcc() etc.) iterates through different combinations of a text string checking for certain parameters. I'll throw an example in the comments